# Matlab Program for solving a 2D wave equation using Finite Difference method

Tags: matlab, wave

The Following is my Matlab code to simulate a 2D wave equation using with a Gaussian source using the finite difference method. I'm not being able to solve it correctly and for some reason I'm getting weird results. It would be of great help if you could point out where my code was wrong. Thank you.

```
c0=3e8;         % speed of light or any wave
e0=8.854e-12;   % free space permittivity
u0=1.2566e-6;   % free space permeability

size=200;        % size of free space

s=size;            % s determines the position of the source in the free space

source_position=size/s; % if s=2, source is at the middle of the free space
                        % if s=1, source is at the end of the free space
                        % if s=size, source is at the beginning of the free space etc.

dx=0.001;        % spatial increment

dt=dx/(c0);   % time increment

cons=c0*dt/dx; % constant term of electric and magnetic field equations

n=200; % total time

% u=zeros(1,size); 
u_n=zeros(size); %next time
t=zeros(size);   %present time
u_p=zeros(size); %previous time

[u,v] = meshgrid(1:200,1:200);

t0=15;   % t0 of Gaussian source 
tp=5;   % tp of Gaussian source

for k=1:n
    for i=2:size-1
    for j=2:size-1      
        u_n(i,j)= 2*t(i,j)-u_p(i,j)+(cons^2)*( u(i+1,j)+u(i-1,j)-2*u(i,j)-2*v(i,j)+v(i,j+1)+v(i,j-1) );
    end
    end
u_p=u;
t=u_n;

u(source_position)=exp(-((k-t0)/tp)^2);
% u(source_position)=sin(2*pi*0.03*i);
surf(u,v,t)
A(k)=getframe;
end
```

Comment: Just a tip: don't use size as a variable name as it's not good practice due to size being a MATLAB built-in function.

Comment: One immediate problem I saw is you didn't use proper time increment. If your for loop, time increment is set to 1. It should be `for k = 1:dt:n`.

Comment: thanks for that tip. But I,m still unable to code it properly. It'd be of great help if any of you has a source code of this problem in Matlab, I desperately need one. The ones that I found on the internet uses the convolution function which I can neither use nor understand. Can anyone provide me with a solution using the FDM/discretized equation?